# bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1

Tags: pg-promise

- I am using pg-promise to execute the following query

Here is the raw query variable

```
const query = `SELECT * FROM feed_items WHERE feed_item_id=$1 AND '{$2}' <@ tags`
```

- tags is an array and I want to check if item is present in the array
- I keep getting this error bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1 despite supplying 2 values
  Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong

Comment: `'{$2}'` is considered just text, not a variable, since you placed it into quotes. Hence the error.

Comment: '{sometag}' <@ tags is how the in array query actually works so how do I put the value sometag

Comment: Prepared Statements won't let you do that, they are too limited. But `pg-promise` native formatting can do anything. For example, using [filters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#formatting-filters): `'{$2#}'` or `'{$2:value}'` is just one possible approach.

Comment: thank you very much! followed this here https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html#.value and it works! truly amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared Statements won't let you do it, because it is too limited. But `pg-promise` native formatting is quite flexible, and you can do it in several ways...

- Via [':value' filter](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#open-values), you can use either `'{$2#}'` or `{$2:value}`
- Via [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting), you can use `$2` directly, while wrapping the value into the following:

```js
const wrap = a => ({rawType: true, toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format('{$1#}', [a])});
```

or like this:

```js
const wrap = a => ({rawType: true, toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format('{$1:value}', [a])});
```

or even like this:

```js
const wrap = a => ({rawType: true, toPostgres: () => `'{${pgp.as.value(a)}}'`});
```

**example:***

```js
await db.any('SELECT ... $1 <@ tags', [wrap(123)]);
//=> SELECT ... '{123}' <@tags'
```